# Create image, then pass it back

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to php but I'm trying to send an image to a buffer or some sort of temporary place where I can access later.  The script I'm calling merges a bunch of images into one, then displays that image (see it in action [here](http://www.charlesanconaequestrian.com/process/mergePhotos.php?jc=2&fb=1&sp=0&cs=2&cc=1&ap=0&p=0&tc=0&tp=0&pi=0&uc=0&ts=5&dt=0&uf=0&fc=0&nh=0&bb=0&rn=0.447166383266449) - change query parameters to change image). Here's a piece of my code so you have an idea of how that's happening:

```
$dest = imagecreatefrompng($img0);
$src12 = imagecreatefrompng($img12); 
    imagecolortransparent($src12, imagecolorat($src12, 0, 0));  
//copy and merge 

$src12_x = imagesx($src12);
$src12_y = imagesy($src12); 
imagecopymerge($dest, $src12, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src12_x, $src12_y, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

However, this is an external script so I'd like to be able to pull that image from another page. I'm not sure what the best way to do it is... temporarily store it or pass the image back through.  The one constraint is that the image has to exist before the content of the parent page is loaded.  How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you mean;

1) You want to pull the image from another website and save it to disk, you can do this;

```
file_put_contents("img.png", file_get_contents("URL-TO-IMAGE"));
```

2) You want to just display it? As the URL aboves headers are to display an image, you can put it right into an IMG tag.

```
<img src="URL-TO-IMAGE">
```

Comment: Am I able to temporarily store it somewhere? The problem stems from the facebook sharer. I can display the image on the page like you mentioned in method #2, but the facebook scraper doesn't execute the script to pull the image properly. My thought is that if I created the image first (as opposed to on-the-fly), then facebook would grab the image properly. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Im not sure how Facebook deals with images that are removed after being shared, whether they cache them or have their own copy. Does the Facebook sharer not get the image at all? is it blocking it because its on another domain?

Comment: No, what's happening is that the first 3 or 4 times I click the facebook sharer button, it doesn't pull the image. If you click the button enough times, it eventually pulls it properly.  Here's my facebook metadata for the image: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://charlesanconaequestrian.com/process/mergePhotos.php?<?php echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];?>&mt=<?php echo(microtime());?>" /> `